# How to change initial iterator value of my loop to debug in VScode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

How to change initial iterator value of my loop to debug in VScode?

Example: I want debug my code starting i=10. How do I do to select this argument to my debugging? I'm loosing so many time clicking in "Step Over" to investigate my code. I'm using language C

[image: Image VSCode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by either taking the ***user input* --> *i*** (that's inefficient) or else you can change **i** while debugging in vs code

Here is a image for reference
[image: Image for reference in VS Code]

But incase you only want to check when **i is k(some constant)** **without skipping** the iterations below it(when **i<k**), you can use `if(i>=k){code}`

Comment: this is inneficient for me, because my code work as matrix. so i need true interations to complete my code. I can't ignore procedures from i=0. i=1. i=2

Comment: In that case a effective solution would be to add a `if(i>9)` above the `if (incrementa == 1)`

Comment: @noob000000 As far as my knowledge is concerned I don't know any way to do this in VS Code

Comment: most important variable in my code is "FactValue". I need to investigate the error when the fact value is 11. I am currently running my code factValue = 10 and seeing the results of my v[i]'s and debugging my code manually  using Excel to fact value =11

Comment: @noob000000 So basically you want to check for a condition when your **FactValue** is 11.You can just use `if(FactValue >= 11){condition}` and then use *step over or continue* to check

Comment: you are so smart. thanks bro @Programmerabc . Sorry for my bad expression, I'm learning English

Answer (score 1):

Another option is a conditional breakpoint. Its condition can be when `i` has a specific value.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The big advantage is: you don't need to recompile your code.

Comment: This is the only correct answer!

Comment: if you want to break at a particular value of `i` you should use `Expression`, it could be that the start value of the loop is variable

Comment: Right, using the expression is even better.

Answer (score 0):

The universal quick & dirty solution no matter debugger is to modify the code. For example:

```c
if(i==0)
{
  volatile int x = 0; // set breakpoint here
}
```

It's also good practice to surround such "debug only" code with a so-called "compiler switch": `#ifdef DEBUG_MODE ... #endif`. So that you don't forget to remove the code and it makes it to release build by accident (*very* common problem).